# Переход на другую страницу локального сайта

Tags: html

У меня такой вопрос - как сделать ссылку на локальном сайте для перехода на другую страницу моего сайта(предварительно создал отдельный html документ)  Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Вам необходимо использовать пример относительной ссылки.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Тег А, атрибут href</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p><a href="../../example/knob.html">Относительная ссылка</a></p>
  <p><a href="http://htmlbook.ru/example/knob.html">Абсолютная ссылка</a></p>
 </body>
</html>
```